# DC/OS on AWS Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, dcos

How to deploy and run DC/OS on AWS Free Tier?
The Free Tier allows only `t2.micro` instances only and gives 750h/month free.

I tried to edit the DC/OS Amazon S3 template replacing the `m3.xlarge` instances with `t2.micro` but the deployment failed.

The error I got was:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [PublicSlaveServerGroup, SlaveServerGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.

CREATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  PublicSlaveServerGroup  Virtualization type 'hvm' is required for instances of type 't2.micro'. 

Ensure that you are using an AMI with virtualization type 'hvm'. For more information, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

Comment: It is not recommended to deploy DC/OS on t3.micro - https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/aws/.

Comment: Either it will fail or few of services might not work

Comment: @Aky_0788 ty for copy paste the info I already seen :) + it is said "Selecting smaller-sized VMs is not recommended" but works ) "selecting fewer VMs will likely cause certain resource-intensive services, such as distributed datastores, to not work properly". And I'm not trying to select fewer VMs ...

Comment: I tried same thing sometime back and got errors, learnt it hard way that why unrecommended things should not be tried

Comment: If you or anybody is able to solve I will be glad, will help me too :)

Comment: I highly doubt that this will work. The t2.micro instances have too little memory to run anything useful, if even DC/OS at all. Might not be worth trying and wasting your time.

Comment: Maybe the problem that you are facing is that you need Instance Storage (t3 are using only EBS). m3 is the family that has Instance Storage https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/. Try with m3.medium, it's a bit cheaper than m3.xlarge (although 6x more costly than t2.micro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC/OS does not operate within a small enough resource envelope to be run on free-tier AWS EC2 instances.

Specifically, DC/OS networking components require at least 2 cores per node.

t2.micro (free tier) has only 1 vCPU and 1 GB memory.

Aside from the hard CPU constraint, DC/OS consists of >30 component services which can use a significant amount of memory, especially on master nodes. While it may be possible to deploy DC/OS masters with 1 GB memory, virtual memory, and swapping, the experience will not be enjoyable. Agents with 1 GB memory will have half of that reserved for the system, and half for user tasks, which means you wont be able to deploy much.

If you want to try DC/OS for free, try the containerized or virtualized local deployments:

- https://github.com/dcos/dcos-docker
- https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant